# php script deleting row automatically somehow - can not find the culprit

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a cron that runs a php script. This script is used for a queue table in the database. The queue table holds jobs that need to be done. When a job is run, the queue table has a column that I use for the status column. When it is set to 1, I know the job is still running. When the script finishes, it sets the flag to 2. Now this was working totally fine, until a couple days ago.

First off... just so I make this clear, the cron script does not have a DELETE function in it.

Somehow, after logging and looking at everything in mysql, I see after the job starts running, a DELETE command comes through, for the current job running. So it deletes the row in the queue table.

I have no idea where this is coming from, because there is no cron job anywhere that is running to do that.

The mysql log only shows me the DELETE statement. But I am trying to find the culprit script doing this...

Any ideas on any way to log the offending script calling that command somehow?

Hopefully this all make sense. ;)

Comment: So, would you like to show us some code or should we make wild guesses?

Comment: It has to do with your code. Too bad we can't see it.

Comment: Can down vote me to death... but either way you look at it, the cron that is running, does not have a delete statement in it. There is actually no cron running that has a delete statement in it period. So... as the original question asks... Can you think of a way to log where the delete command is originating from? That was my actual question. As of right now I have done grep on everything related to this application. Looked at every cron in the system, as well.

My question had nothing to do with seeing the code, but an idea on how to log where the query to mysql originated.

Comment: Does your doctor diagnose you himself or treat you solely based on what you told him ?

Comment: Do people answer specific questions, or just come up with cute things to say here? Easier to just say... I don't know of anyway to log something like that, other then the mysql log, which will tell you nothing, but the query being run. Don't see where it is so hard to just not answer, if you can't stick to the actual question at hand. My questions doesn't require the cron code to be looked at. Either there is a way to log where a query originated from or not. Same code that has been running for months. I have already went through the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually started logging all queries for mysql. Then logged all proccesses that were run by a specific username. Then I matched the timestamps up, and found the associated problematic script. Which was actually on another site, that still had the database information from the problematic server. Since there were no delete functions in the scripts used for the cron, like I repeatedly said, it wasn't too hard to track it down after this.

So yes, there was a way to do it.